# Converse of Maschke theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let F be a field and G be a group and FG the group ring. Let H:=$\{\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_g g\in FG : \sum_{g\in G}\lambda_g=0\}$.

1. Then H is codimension 1 subspace of FG and is an FG submodule. Moreover FG/H is trivial.
2. Show that the span of $\sum_{g\in G } g$ is the only 1 dimensional trivial FG submodule  of FG if G is finite. Prove that H does not have a complementary submodule if the characteristic of F is positive and divides order of G.

I proved it is a FG submodule. I cannot justify why it has codimension 1 and FG/H is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

If you view $FG$ as a vector space spanned by the elements of $G$ and $H$ the subspace whose coordinates sum to zero, then it should be easy to see that $H$ is of codimension 1. For the second part of your first question, for any $h\in G$, $h\cdot\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_g g-\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_g g=\sum_{g\in G}(\lambda_{gh^{-1}}-\lambda_g)g$, and the sum of coefficients $\sum_{g\in G}(\lambda_{gh^{-1}}-\lambda_g)=\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_{gh^{-1}}-\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_g=0$ because $\{\lambda_{gh^{-1}}\}_{g\in G}$ is just a permutation of $\{\lambda_g\}_{g\in G}$. Hence the difference lies inside $H$ and $FG/H$ is a trivial module over $FG$.

Comment: OK. Sir can you tell me some suggestions for part 2 of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the subspace is of codimension 1 is pure linear algebra; it is defined by a single linear equation. The fact that the action on the quotient is trivial follows from the fact that for each $g$ we have that $g-e$ is in the kernel, where $e$ is the identity element, so every element acts as the identity.